# Why mongo login without auth data?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I create admin-user for some db. Look dump:

```
>db.system.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("533aa7175572233602378633"),
    "user" : "root",
    "pwd" : "06dbc97127a71ab5b359a6a6e9ff5f53",
    "roles" : [
        "readWrite",
        "userAdmin",
        "dbAdmin",
        "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase"
    ]
}
```

Check login:

`mongo some_db -u root -p 5415` - **ok!**

`mongo some_db -u root -p 54153` - **error!**

`mongo some_db` - **ok!** Why this method allows you to enter into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `auth` configuration to true to require authentication.

**Important tip:** If you set the option to true but you don't have any users you can still connect using "localhost" from inside the server

Source [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#auth)

Comment: `auth = true` - it was

Comment: Awesome, will be really nice if you accept my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, but you not help me. This variable has already been set in my config file.

Comment: sorry I misunderstand  you

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access anything because you are not authenticated.